# Getting error message after stop the recording in loadrunner

Tags: correlation, loadrunner

I am new in loadrunner.

When record sample project web tour in load runner, after stop the recording its showing error: "one of the post generation procedure has failed. failed procedure: performing scan for correlation post generation operation"

Can anyone help to resolve this issue. I am stuck here and not able to work further.

Comment: I know this is a bit late but have you tried un-checking the auto correlation implementation in LR recording options and tried recording the script again?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools-->Options-->Scriptin
Check  `**Enable C language parser**` option
It should be ok